# Converted vfat to linux with cfdisk, now cannot mount it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

With cfdisk, I converted my vfat thumb drive to linux, but now I cannot mount the device.  Here is what happens when I try.

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63    31266815    15633376+  83  Linux
/home/g mount -t ext2 /dev/sdc /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc1 /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount -t ext2 /dev/sdc1 /16gb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

/home/g mount /dev/sdc1 /16gb
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
/home/g mount /dev/sdc /16gb
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
/home/g
```

Comment: You converted the partition type, but did you also format it with mkfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cfdisk creates the partitions. You still need to format them to match the filesystem you need. I don't know what you have in mind for your configuration, but let's say you want to format a partition to work in EXT3:

> mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc1

Then you can try to mount.

Comment: `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc1`, actually...

Comment: Oops. Sorry for that forgetting that. And thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

`cfdisk` and friends only alters the partition table; it doesn't alter the contents of the partitions themselves.  So if you took a brand new drive filled with zeros and wrote a fresh partition table to it, the partitions themselves would still be filled with zeros, and unrecognizable to the OS.

Filesystems are initialized using the tool `mkfs` ("make filesystem"), whose synopsis is:

```
mkfs [options] [-t type fs-options] device [size]
```

In your case, to initialize partition `/dev/sdc1` with a new EXT3 filesystem with default options, you would say:

```
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdc1
```

Obviously, this obliterates any data that was already present in `/dev/sdc1`.